# proper translation of multi-dimensional array to JSON (and back)

Tags: json

Is there a standard way of translating multi-dimensional arrays to JSON and back? Does this depend on the language and the relationship between byte ordering and rows/columns/pages etc.? I am working working in Matlab. In Matlab, an array of integers, with values of say 1 through 10, with a shape of 5 x 2, would have the following 2-D layout:

1 6
2 7
3 8
4 9
5 10

as opposed to:

1 2
3 4
5 6
7 8
9 10

The question is, if I translate the 2-D array into a JSON string, should I get:
`[[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10]]`
or
`[[1,6],[2,7],[3,8],[4,9],[5,10]]`

My preference would be the first case, since it is sequential in terms of memory access.

So the explicit question then is, which way are n-d arrays written?

1. By memory - innermost should be sequential in memory
2. high to low dimensions - innermost is lowest dimension (which in this case matches the memory for Matlab)
3. low to high dimensions - innermost is highest dimension

Comment: The JSON specification doesn't say anything about dimensionality at all. Arrays in JSON are always one dimensional. However the elements in an array can be anything including other arrays.

Comment: Yeah, I figured the JSON specification(s) didn't say anything. I was hoping someone could make a convincing argument that there was a right and a wrong way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you say you have a 5x2 array, in JS you probably mean you have an array of length of 5, each element of which is an array of length 2. So the "layout" you get is:

```
[ [a00, a01],
  [a10, a11],
  [a20, a21],
  [a30, a31],
  [a40, a41] ]
```

Decoding that in terms of 1..10 is entirely up to you.

> an array of integers, with values of say 1 through 10, with a shape of 5 x 2

There is no single correct way to put values 1..10 into an array 5x2. So `[[1,6],[2,7],[3,8],[4,9],[5,10]]` would be just as good as `[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[9,10]]`.